# 2002 Honda civic free spins with new starter, ry plus had all of them checked. I had battery light on and off for 30 miles before

Tags: honda, civic

drove about 25 miles with battery light on and off. now trying to crank and it just spins. bought new battery, alternator, and starter, same results. went and had each one checked and all were good. I hear one click in glove box after 3 seconds

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! So I understand, you can turn the key and the engine turns over, but there's no life (does not sound like it's going to start)? Is that correct? And it was doing the same thing before you put the new alternator/battery/starter in?

Comment: Is it just the starter motor that is spinning without turning the engine over?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "spinning." Does it make a high-pitched sound a bit like a drill? Or is the motor turning over?

Comment: motor isn't turning other than by hand/socket. and yes starter spinning but not engaging. MTA  says it could be a gear that works with the flywheel which I wasn't aware of such gear.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go out on a limb and tell you what I think the problem is. I think there's more to this story than you have revealed -- why replace the battery, alternator and starter? We can only guess.

So I will guess, because I know someone who had this exact thing happen, as follows.

The last time your car was working normally, when you started the car the ignition switch got stuck in the "Start" position but you did not realize it. The car started, but it was making a weird noise. You continued driving anyway with the starter engaged. For. Twenty. Five. Miles.

During this drive, the failing ignition switch intermittently engaged the starter due to vibration and general cussedness. When it did, the battery light came on.

At the end of your drive, you parked and turned off the engine. When you tried to start the engine again, nothing happened because the starter was completely destroyed during your drive but you didn't know that. So you replaced the battery. That didn't help so you replaced the alternator. That didn't help either, so you replaced the starter.

Now we're getting somewhere! Now the starter spins but does not crank the engine. That's because when you ran the car with the starter engaged, the starter's spur gear destroyed the ring gear on your engine's flywheel. There are no teeth for the starter to engage, or many teeth are missing.

If you want to check the ring gear teeth, remove the starter and look into the hole in the engine where the starter goes using a flashlight and a mirror. Do you see perfectly shaped teeth? Broken / worn down teeth? Missing teeth?

The bad news is that if this is what happened, you will need either a new flywheel or -- if Hondas have replaceable ring gears -- a new ring gear. The only good news is that you now have a new battery, starter and alternator.

Check your ignition switch and see if it is sticking in the Start position when you release it. If it is, it should be replaced. If replacement is not in the budget right now, physically return the ignition switch to the On position after starting. Make sure it does not stick in Start.

The takeaways:

- If your car is making a weird noise, stop as soon as possible.
- When the car has a problem, don't throw parts at it and hope it fixes the problem.
- Diagnose, diagnose, diagnose. Then repair.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply with your hypothesis and just like you said I've been guessing but I didn't hear any unusual noises. had a bad valve cover leak/spurt right on top of alternator so after fixing gasket is when I tried starting and yes just spins not engaging!

Comment: @todd1762 You'll know what you're dealing with as soon as you take a peek at the ring gear after removing the starter as suggested. If you find the ring gear clean and perfectly intact, the only rational explanation is that the new starter has a bad Bendix drive. This is the internal mechanism that forces the starter's spur gear (pinion gear) to shoot forward and engage the flywheel's ring gear. You can bench test the starter with a car battery and jumper cables to see if the Bendix drive is working or not. If it is not, you got a bad starter.

Comment: don't know how to post a picture but every fuse has had a load on it (a white contact and rest is blackened/burnt but still working) but I replaced. I'll look at gears shortly and again thank you!